# Video пост в WordPress теме

Tags: wordpress

Создаю в WordPress новую статью с типом video (поддержка данного типа поста в functions.php задана):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В **content-video.php** пытаюсь вывести как-то так:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php 
        // If not a single post, highlight the gallery.
        if ( ! is_single() ) {


            if ( has_post_format( 'video' ) ) {
                echo '<div class="entry-video">';
                    $url = get_post_format( get_the_ID(), 'video' ); ?>

                    <iframe src="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

                <?php echo '</div>';

            };

        };
    ?> ......
```

Но ни в превью статьи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ни на странице самой статьи (подробное описание) видео не отображается.

**Вопрос:** как вывести на странице (в общем блоге или на страницу статьи) WordPress темы пост с видео/само видео (загруженное или с другого сайта youtube, vimeo, ...) ?

**P.S:** без дополнительных плагинов и доп. кастомных полей.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо никаких игр с url. Просто:

```
the_content();
```

Comment: Помимо видео еще и текст есть под видео. Если это превью статьи, то выводится и контент http://prntscr.com/l2gxi3. А на странице самой статьи текст есть, а видео так же и нет http://prntscr.com/l2gxpm почему-то.

Comment: Надо смотреть код, который это выводит

Comment: А почему не сделать вывод миниатюры? А уже когда откроют пост, то смогут посмотреть видео. get_post_format() - возвращает формат (тип) поста, например: quote, status, video, audio. Каким образом вы хотели там увидеть ссылку на само видео?

Comment: Я ничего не хотел увидеть, кроме кода, который выводит не то, что хотелось бы.